# NodeJS-MSSQL Can't even execute select command

Tags: sql-server, node.js, redis

I am trying to select top 1 record from my MSSQL table using Node JS. This is the code I am using:

```
var qryString = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AppUsers";

db.getConnPoolPromise().then(function(connPool) {
                var sqlRequest = new sql.Request(connPool);
                return sqlRequest.query(qryString);
            }).then(function(result) {
                cb(null, result);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Query Error' + err);
                cb(err, null);
            });
```

But this never executes. The control always go to "event.js" and the error details are:

```
{
    "message": "ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command",
    "stack": "ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command at parseError (c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\NodeApp\\services\\nodejs\\node_modules\\redis-parser\\lib\\parser.js:193:12) at parseType (c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\NodeApp\\services\\nodejs\\node_modules\\redis-parser\\lib\\parser.js:303:14)",
    "command ": "SET ",
    "args": [
        "auth - 1234 ",
        {
            "recordset": [{
                "Id": "13892",
                "Pin": "200757",
                "CellPhoneNumber": "1234567890",
                "CountryId": "1",
                "UserId": "1234"
            }]
        },
        "EX",
        "43200"
    ],
    "code": "ERR",
    "name": "ReplyError"
}
```

This is driving me crazy. Don't know what is the issue? Whare is the SET command? I have Redis server running locally and configured using AWS CLI

Comment: Which version of Redis are you using?

Comment: @LEQADA I am using version 2.4.6.0

Comment: Try to update it to the latest stable version. According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/issues/164) "Redis older than 2.6.12 doesn't support `SET` at all"